# How does as Mutex relate to a Semaphore?

Tags: c#, multithreading, mutex, semaphore

Add: ok, so i can seperate the mutex and semaphore, and i just want to know is that my idea of counter right?
namely Release minus one and WaitOne add one, only if the counter bigger than zero, it will allow to run.
is this statement right?

I have some code that works well: run first() second() third() in order.

I just want to know how the counter in semaphore works? I know it is counter. Is that Release minus one and WaitOne add one, only if the counter bigger than zero, it will allow to run. Right?

However I read book about another thing, Mutex, the book says Mutex Waitone minus one, and release add one, so mutex is opposite to the semaphore? Right?

Code:

```
using System;

namespace Algorithm.MultiThread
{
    class Semaphore
    {
        System.Threading.Semaphore s1, s2;
        public Semaphore()
        {
            s1 = new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 5);
            s2 = new System.Threading.Semaphore(1, 5); //initialize as start counter 1
        }

        public void first()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("First");
            s1.Release(); // minus one
        }

        public void second()
        {
            s1.WaitOne(); //add one two times
            s1.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Second");
            s2.Release();
        }

        public void third()
        {
            s2.WaitOne(); // add one two times
            s2.WaitOne();
            Console.WriteLine("Third");

        }

        public void startnum(object obj)
        {
            int i = (int)obj;
            switch (i)
            {
                case 1:
                    first();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    second();
                    break;
                case 3:
                    third();
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        public static void test()
        {
            Semaphore s = new Semaphore();
            System.Threading.Thread t1 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(s.startnum));
            System.Threading.Thread t2 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(s.startnum));
            System.Threading.Thread t3 = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(s.startnum));
            t1.Start(3);
            t2.Start(2);
            t3.Start(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A mutex is a special-case of a semaphore (count = 1).

Comment: A mutex works very differently from a semaphore, you can't compare them.  A mutex is owned by a thread and is re-entrant by the owner thread.  A semaphore doesn't have any thread affinity.

Comment: @HansPassant +1 , but, when speaking about their functionality from the coder point of view, a semaphore of count=1 is just like a mutex, isn't it ?

Comment: No, you can't compare them from a coder point of view.  By far the most common use of a synchronization object is to protect shared state, ensuring that only one thread can access it at the same time.  Properly addressed by a mutex.  A semaphore is prone to cause deadlock in such usage, it is not re-entrant.

Answer (score 5):

A mutex is basically a special case of a semaphore.  It can be thought of (even though it wouldn't actually be implemented as) a semaphore that starts at one and can't ever be greater than one.

Imagine a `Semaphore` as a wrapper around an integer and a `mutex` as a wrapper around a boolean.  It only has two states, free or locked.

Comment: Well, there's a bit more to it than that - see @Hans comment.

Comment: -1 What Martin James said plus a local semaphore exists only within your process.

Answer (score 1):

Mutex is just like having a Semaphore with only one allowed thread.

Mutex only allows a single access to a resource at once, while semaphore can be set to allow any preset number of concurrent access to a resource or a piece of code.

Edit:

Both can be used across different processes if they are named.

Comment: -1 This may be a good explanation on a non-technical forum. There are important differences.